# Numpy prints a vector of rows, where I expected a vector of vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4x1 vector v, and I reshape it to 2x1x2, so to a vector of vectors, w.

```
v=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
print(v)
w=np.reshape(v,(2,1,2))
print(w)
```

But it prints a vector of rows:

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]

[[[1 2]]

 [[3 4]]]
```

I expected something like:

```
[[[1]
  [2]]
 [[3]
  [4]]]
```

Comment: When you reshape, your last axis is dimension 2, and the innermost array has 2 elements. It seems like you wanted shape (2, 2, 1), i.e. the innermost array has only one element.

Comment: What would be `w[1,0,1]` in your expected array? It should exist, if the shape is `(2,1,2)`

Comment: I see 2 blocks of (1,2) arrays (separated by blank line).  In `numpy` 'vector' is ambiguous.  (2,), (1,2), (2,1) might all be described as 2 element vectors shapes.  Or they could described as 1d array, 'row vector' and 'column vector', or just 1 row array, 1 column array.

Comment: @xzkzyz You are right. I am used to matlab, and there they start with the inner dimensions. Numpy starts with the outer dimensions. So in numpy 2,2,1 or 2,1,2,1 gives a vector with vectors.